Issue loading SSL Certificate in HCL Domino 12 - resolved
This has been resolved.  The server needed a complete reboot, not just the HTTP Task.  This is now working as expected.
Having an issue with HCL Domino 12 and installing an SSL Certificate using the new process.  Have reviewed the documentation and appear to have completed al steps?
I have used the CertMgt and CertStore to create new SSL Certificates for the website.  However the website is still using the old kyr file and is showing the old certificate.
I have restarted HTTP task and the server is still not using the correct certificate.  Cannot reboot the server atm (waiting for an outage).
When  I check CertMgt using
tell certmgr show certs

It says that the certificate is valid.  Also, when looking in the certstore,NSF is shows that the certificate is valid and OK.  It simply (?) seems that the server is now using the correct certificate.
I have checked the kyr file and that has not been updated, however I believe that it is no longer updated so that might not be an issue?
This is the first time using certmgr - server was running v10 last year so we used the openssl commands.

This was resolved by rebooting the server.
